# Using operator overloading in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
class A
{
public:
    ostream& operator<<(int  string)
    {
        cout << "In Overloaded function1\n";
        cout << string << endl;
    }
};

main()
{
    int temp1 = 5;
    char str = 'c';
    float p= 2.22;
    A a;
    (a<<temp1);
    (a<<str);
    (a<<p);
    (a<<"value of p=" << 5);
}
```

I want the output to be: value of p=5

What changes should is do...and the function should accept all data type that is passed

Comment: I think you're looking for templates, but I don't know for sure (I'm new at C++ as well).

Comment: @Matt: Why it suddenly becomes "homework"?

Comment: @KennyTM It's a classic "please do my homework" question - a sample program, a description of what the input and output should be, and no plan or idea of where to start or indication that the OP has attempted it.

Comment: @KennyTM although I did mean to edit the tags rather than the title. I shall fix that.

Comment: 'int string' is one of the worst declarations I have seen in a while

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 solutions.

First solution is to make it a template.

```
            template <typename T>
            ostream& operator<<(const T& input) const
            {
                    cout << "In Overloaded function1\n";
                    return (cout << input << endl);
             }
```

However, this will make the `a << str` and `a << p` print `c` and `2.22`, which is different from your original code. that output `99` and `2`.

The second solution is simply add an overloaded function for `const char*`:

```
            ostream& operator<<(int  string)
            {
                    cout << "In Overloaded function1\n";
                    return (cout << string << endl);
             }

            ostream& operator<<(const char*  string)
            {
                    cout << "In Overloaded function1\n";
                    return (cout << string << endl);
             }
```

This allows C strings and everything convertible to `int` to be `A <<`'ed, but that's all — it won't "accept all data type that is passed".

---

BTW, you have forgotten to `return` the `ostream`.

Comment: Would have +1ed if I saw 'return input?' Some 'const' correctness is also not right here?

Comment: @Chubsdad: No, you should return an `ostream`, not the `input` (see update). Please explain "Some 'const' correctness is also not right here?".

Comment: earlier the 'return' statement was not there I guess. Now it is fine. Upvoted. Pls ignore my comment on const correctness. Somehow, I am used to see operator << as a namespace friend (or similar) rather than a member function.

Comment: Is `string` a valid variable name? I guess, if `<string>` was not included, right?

Comment: @dreamlax: Yes. Even if `<string>` was included and `using namespace std`'ed, it is *still* a valid name as the `string` parameter shadows the `std::string` type. Of course OP shouldn't use confusing names like this as the parameter name, but that's a minor point.

Comment: @dreamlax, Kenny: aren't variable and type identifiers in different namespaces (grammatical, not C++ namespaces)? A variable named `string` wouldn't affect the visibility of a type named `string` (though it would shadow `string`'s constructor, so you couldn't call it explicitly where the `string` variable was in scope). As `string` isn't a keyword, it's valid.

Comment: Hmm, looks like an imported string type is shadowed by the variable (at least, gcc chokes on `void foo(int string) {string bar;}`). Time to dig through the standard.